# How to set the value of an HTML input field with a javascript value

Tags: javascript, html, input, getelementbyid

I know this has been asked a thousand times but nothing I've tried has worked so far. I'd really appreciate some input.
Here's my situation,
I have this code in javascript:

```
<script>
var url = document.URL;
url = url.slice(17,21);
</script>
```

I need the value of `url` in a html input field which looks like this:

```
<input name="name" type="text"/>
```

I've tried with `getElementbyId` and it shows me nothing.

Is there something I've missed?

Comment: well, if you're using a method called getElementById, wouldn't you expect the element you try to get to actually have an id ?

Comment: Add attribute id i.e. id="name" to input field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
<script>
      window.onload=function(){
        var url = document.URL;
        url = url.slice(17,21);
        document.getElementById("urlText").value=url;
      }          
</script>
```

In the HTML input tag change it as ,

```
<input id="urlText" name="name" type="text"/>
```

Comment: YES! It works, thank you so much, you have no idea how much time I've wasted on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Change your html to look like this, you forgot to set the id.

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
```

and then your js will look like this

```
    var url = document.URL;
    url = url.slice(17,21);
    document.getElementById("name").value = url;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've changed it to this:         <script>
        
        
          var url = document.URL;
        url = url.slice(17,21);
getElementById("name")=document.write="url"
document.write="url";
     </script>

And <input id="name" name="name"/> 
But still nothing

Comment: @user2497085 see my above edit, that shows you how the js should look like

Comment: @user2497085 and dont forget to set the type to text

Comment: Thank you again for answering, turns out the thing I forgot to add was the window.onload

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var url = document.URL;
   url = url.slice(17,21);
   var urlField = document.getElementsByName('name')[0];
   url.value=url;
</script>
```

This assumes, that you have only one tag with name-attribute = "name", though. Else add an `id`attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one.
**HTML:**

```
<input id="textBox" type="text"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var url = document.URL;
url = url.slice(17,21);
document.getElementById("textBox").value = url;
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/pK3T7/)